# How to modify the parameters of ROS 2 in real-time?

Tags: ros2, parameters, real-time

We know that parameters can be adjusted dynamically in ROS, for example, when using the TEB local planner, the parameters can be dynamically adjusted. In ROS 1, I did this:

```
Client=dynamic_ Configure.client.Client("/movebase/TobLocalPlannerROS", timeout=20)
Client.update_Configuration({"planner_frequency": 5.0})
```

The above process is basically not time-consuming

In ROS 2, I also want to modify `teb_local_planner` parameters in this way, but it seems that parameter modification is done through service response in ROS 2, for example:

```
import time
import os
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from rcl_interfaces.srv import SetParameters, GetParameters, ListParameters

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    node = rclpy.create_node('my_node')
    client = node.create_client(GetParameters, '/controller_server/get_parameters')
    start = time.time()
    while not client.wait_for_service(timeout_sec=0.1):
        node.get_logger().info('Service not available, waiting again...')
    request = GetParameters.Request()
    request.names = ['FollowPath.acc_lim_x']
    future = client.call_async(request)
    while rclpy.ok():
        rclpy.spin_once(node)
        if future.done():
            try:
                response = future.result()
                end = time.time()
                print("time: ", end - start)
                print("responce: ",  response.values[0].double_value)
                node.get_logger().info('Service call succeeded')
            except Exception as e:
                node.get_logger().info('Service call failed %r' % (e,))
            break
    node.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then I printed the time on the terminal and found that every time I run the code, the time is not fixed and cannot guarantee real-time modification. Is there any other way to modify parameters in real time?